# What is the independent variable?

Tags: self-study

This question will more than likely be extremely simple for most of you, but the way the scenario is worded has me confused.

Scenario:
The communication quality of couples three month before and again three month after marriage were tested. It was assumed that the communication quality would decrease after marriage. One group studied was 19 couples who had received ordinary premarital counselling from the ministers who were going to marry them. The scores for the 19 husbands are listed as before and after.

Question: What is the independent variable of the above?

I understand the difference between IV and DV, however I'm unsure if the IV is marriage or the fact that 19 couples received premarital counselling due to the way the question is worded.

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: One way to think about this is to note that the independent variable has to *vary*. Since all the couples were married, and all received counseling, neither marriage nor counseling can be the IV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the two variables are the communication index before marriage and the communication index after marriage. I would use the index before marriage as the covariate, because the regression model would allow to predict the index after marriage given the index before marriage. This is not a theoretical reason, but a practical one: using the index after marriage as the covariate would be less useful.

Comment: Thank you for your hasty response, by index before marriage do you mean the before marriage test score?

Comment: @user5334 Yes, exactly ("before marriage index" would have been more English ? I have learnt a lesson :)

Comment: I personally think they're interchangeable ways of writing the text, thank you again! :)